# Postfix appends hostname instead of domainname to outgoing mail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I did a basic postfix config on my Ubuntu VPS.

When I try to send mail using the command:

```
echo "message" | mail -s "subject" target@example.com
```

The mail fails. Upon inspection, I notice that postfix was trying to send the mail as user@hostname.domain.tld instead of user@hostname.tld
The mail is then rejected on the premise: "host-not-in-DNS return address not allowed" which makes sense.

If I explicitly specify the sender by changing the command to:

```
echo "message" | mail -aFrom "user@domain.tld" -s "subject" target@example.com
```

it works perfectly!

As additional info, here is the result of:

```
hostname
```

hostname.domian.tld

```
/etc/hosts
```

my.vps.ip host.domain.tld host

What Do I need to change in terms of setup to tell postfix to use the correct send form address from the start?

Answer (score 0):

With locally submitted mail Postfix will by default append the string `@$myorigin` to mail addresses without domain information.

Typically the default config sets the value of `myorigin` to  `$myhostname` but you can change that to your domain instead.